# Why is only one rectangle being painted here?

Tags: java, swing, frame

Why is only one rectangle being painted here even though I call the `repaint()` method multiple times in my `for()` loop? Additionally I want to display 8 rectangles per row and 8 rectangles per column with 2 pixels space in between. Any ideas or help?

```
package PROG2;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Model {
    
    int m_width;
    int m_height;
    int m_x1 = 50;
    int m_y1 = 50;      //Information about the model
    int m_x2 = 100;
    int m_y2 = 30;
    int counter = 0;    //Assisting variable
    
    Model(int width,int height) {
        m_width = width;
        m_height = height;
    }
    void math() {
        counter = counter + 2;
        counter = counter + m_x2;
        m_x1 = counter;
    }
}

class View extends JComponent {
        
        private Model m_Mod;
        
        View(Model mod) {
            m_Mod = mod;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            
            //super.paintComponent(g);
            
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.drawRect(m_Mod.m_x1,m_Mod.m_y1,
                    m_Mod.m_x2,m_Mod.m_y2);
            g.fillRect(m_Mod.m_x1,m_Mod.m_y1,
                    m_Mod.m_x2,m_Mod.m_y2);
        }
    
}
        
class Controller {
    
    private Model m_Mod;
    private View m_View;
    
        Controller(){
                m_Mod = new Model(500,500);
                m_View = new View(m_Mod);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(m_View);
                frame.setSize(m_Mod.m_width,m_Mod.m_height);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                //Graphics g = frame.getGraphics();
        }
        void simulate(int right, int down){
            
            for( int i = 0; i < right; i++) {
            m_Mod.math();
            m_View.repaint();
            }
            
        }
        
}
        
class Übung2{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Controller c = new Controller();    
        c.simulate(8, 8);
    }
        
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger?

Comment: Yes. No results.

Comment: I'm confused. Your code is set up to draw *two* rectangles. You will *see* the last two you draw

Comment: The for() loop runs 8 times and calls the repaint() method 8 times. So why is there only 1?

Comment: @Bunsekanse Your `paintComponent()` draws only one `fillRect()`, not eight.

Comment: But I call the ```repaint()``` method in the View Class 8 times, no?

Comment: @Bunsekanse Doesn't matter how often you call `repaint()`. When the view is painted, it will draw one `fillRect()` as written in the method of `paintComponent()`. Keep in mind that the `Graphics` object coming into `paintComponent()` will be empty each time it is called by swing, there is no "previous" drawing.

Comment: How do I solve this problem then and paint multiple rectangles by using a parameter?

Comment: Give your model class a member called `List<Rectangle> rectangles` [we don't use Hungarian notation in Java ;)]. In `View.paintComponent`cast to `Graphics2d`and do `for (Rectangle r : model.getRectangles()) { g2d.draw(r); }` That would be the entire body of `paintComponent` after a precautionary call to `super.paintComponent(g)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when you call `repaint()` multiple times, the actual drawing will take place only once at a later time (until swing will trigger a repaint again). At that time, the content of the `paintComponent()` method is executed. The code you have in your method only draws one rectangle (`drawRect()`) and one filled rectangle (`fillRect()`) and that's it, nothing more. So you don't get more than what you wrote in your method.

You can use arrays (or lists) to store the multiple XY coordinates of your rectangles and then iterate over the array/list to draw multiple rectangles while inside the single call of `paintComponent()`. The code can look like this:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    //super.paintComponent(g);
        
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    foreach (RectModel rect: m_Mod.getRectangles()) {
        g.drawRect(rect.x1, rect.y1, rect.x2, rect.y2);
    }
}
```

This assumes you have such a class `RectModel` which holds the data of one rectangle (`x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`) and that you have a method `m_Mod.getRectangles()` which returns an array/list of `RectModel` instances. When you execute the `simulate()` method in your controller, you will calculate all the rectangles you want to draw and save them in the `this.rectangles` array/list of the `Model` class. After that the `paintComponent()` method fill use that array/list and draws the rectangles.